# GA4 real time report not showing utm tags

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, utm

I can’t see campaign info when i have setup a utm link in GA4 real time report! I can see those campaigns details in source report after 1-2 days! Any one has am idea why I can’t  them in realtime? I have no issue seeing them in UA! So I believe its a GA4 issue!

Answer (score 9):

In the Realtime reports homepage in GA4, I don't see utm params under the leftmost 'Users by First User Source/First User Medium/First User Campaign' report myself.
But if you goto the 'Event Count by Event Name' (rightmost report on that page currently) and click on page_view event in there, then click on the field you are interested in (like medium or campaign or source or term or content), then you should see your respective utm param in there (note: on a property with alot of hits, it may take a minute to get in there).

Here is an example where I added &utm_medium=cpc444 to my url and now see it in the RealTime report:
[image]

Comment: I struggled for some hours to make this work using exploration reports. by inserting in the filters field Medium contains the value I had used in utm_medium but to no avail. I'm not sure what is happening here with GA4. But doing what you mentioned above made stuff appear thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue. Real time reports are meant to be used for very simple event debugging. Any 'calculated' metrics as well as more in-depth dimensions are not meant to be accessed in real-time reports.

The free version of GA normally asks for up to two days until the data is available for reporting.

Paid GA (GA 360) makes the data available in about four hours.

Usually real time is not the best way to debug tracking. If you have info on why it is important for you to see the data quickly, we can suggest better solutions.

Comment: This is not an issue with UA, I can get all the required info from utm tags in UA version! So I assume that I should be able to see that in GA4 as well

Comment: oh, well GA4 has a large number of bugs and missing features at the moment. It's odd that Google tries to push it despite it's poor state. We generally recommend people to use UA and only maintain GA4 so that they would have historical data once Google finishes working on GA4.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this, it is possible to create a Google Analytics GA4 property that is linked to a UA property. The result is two properties with the same name: One with a GA4 ID and the other with a UA ID.

You can deploy the GA4 tag (futureproofing) but still see real-time traffic sources (which I agree are laggy/non-existant in the GA4 view) via the default view of the linked UA property.

[image: Show advanced options]

[image: Create both a Google Analytics 4 and a Universal Analytics property]

[image: Connected site tags]

Answer (score 0):

I have just successfully tested UTM's in Realtime - using GTM (Google Tag Manager) and the GA4 Debug tool.

- Access your GTM account's Preview mode
- Paste in URL with the UTM's
- Go to GA4 - Debug view
- Click on the page_view event
- Click on the parameters - source, medium etc. this should show you the values from your UTM link

I loved the UA Realtime view and very sad to see it go.